# "until next week" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, articles

1. Does "Let's put X off until next week" mean dealing with X during next week or before next week starts?
2. "The" shouldn't follow "until" in the sentence, should it?

Comment: 1. it means dealing with X during the following week. 2. 'the' is not necessary because it is implied, but it is optional if you want to give the sentence a little more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your sentence suggests that we should deal with X during the week after the current one. Just to be clear. For most English speakers, weeks start on Monday.
2. **[next](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/next)** can have several functions in a sentence.

> Next is a performance of traditional country dances- *pronoun*
> What shall we do next? -  *adverb*
> Let's catch the next train - *adjective*
> next time we go to London, we'll visit the Tate Gallery - *determiner*

**next** as a determiner specifies which one you are talking about in relation to now: it works the same as **this**

> The exhibition is open this week and next week.

**the** is also a determiner, and you can only put one determiner in front of a noun, so you cannot put **the** in front of **next** when you are using it as a determiner.

**next** as an adjective requires a determiner, and refers to what follows something that has already been mentioned.

> I enjoyed the walk, but the next day I was very stiff.

Here, **the next day** refers to the day after the walk.

Comment: "For most English speakers, weeks start on Monday." Generally true, but in this case the use might well represent an event which only occurs on a certain day of the week. So, for instance, an issue being discussed at a church meeting (let's say, Sunday) would be put off until the next Sunday.