# I don’t finish until next week. (about "until next week")

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I don’t finish until next week.

Does it mean he will be free next Monday? So, if today is August, 8, he will be free from August, 15. Right? Can "next week" mean in any day during next week in this case (August, 15 - August, 21)?

After [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/271451/until-next-week-meaning), I can understand that "next week" mean in any day during next week. It would be nice to get some additional explanation, if it's possible. In my native language, we use "I don’t finish until next week." if the situation changes next Monday.

Comment: There is no context here. Is the person finishing work, or school, or finishing a break from those things? Are they finishing *permanently*? Are they taking a vacation, a break, what?

Comment: @Astralbee, is it important? Let it be school or work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most of these vague time expressions, it is vague.

Let's assume this is about school, and "finish" refers to finishing the term and starting the summer holiday.

So I would understand that this person will continue to go to school this week (Monday - Friday) and then the first day of the holiday will be some day next week.  It could be Monday next week (in which case their last day will be Friday) or it could be later in the week.

If their last day is Friday, they might say "I finish this week" or "I finish next week", depending on how they calculate ending on Friday. If you want to say  "Yes, I can come drinking with you on Friday evening because I finish this week". Or "No, I can't go scuba diving with you on Friday morning because I don't finish till next week."  -  Do you see why even though Friday this week is the last day of school, the speaker might use different expressions in different contexts to communicate different ideas.

It's a vague expression with vague meaning.

Comment: I have a similar problem with the use of **next** in references to days.  For example, if today is Monday, is **next Saturday** the coming Saturday or the one after.  And if it's the coming Saturday, when does it change from being **next** to **this**?

Comment: Yes, there is no consensus on what is the first and what is the last day of the week.  For some Monday is the first and Sunday is the last, for some Friday is the last, so Saturday is the first, and for some Saturday is the last and Sunday is the first.  Of course only one of these is right and both the others are heretical and absolutely wrong.